# Mongoose: how to get warnings on undocumented fields?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If I have the following Schema for my colletion
 `new Schema({ name: String })`

I then mistakenly try to create a model for this schema
 `new Model({name: 'Manu', address: '5 Rosier Road'}).save()`

The `address` field is not stated in the schema and so is not added to the document and only `{name: 'Manu'}` is saved.

This is the normal behavior but I would like to have mongoose warn me that my code sends too much data.

Is there any way to configure mongoose to warn on such things ? Any plugin I can find to do so ?

I think it would be a very valuable info to have to detect bugs and mongoose knows how to detect them already

Answer (score 0):

Since additional data are not saved into MongoDB, why it should provide warnings?

To my understanding, MongoDB works on Key-Value pairs. So, key-value can be in any order, but, it will saved as per schema definition.

I also think it is developer's responsibility to check the data before inserting into the database. I personally validate the fields before inserting into the database via code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think mongoose could provide a warning because : it detects that you have done something wrong by providing unnecessary data and silently dismisses it whereas it is a valuable info IMO

Comment: Thats good to hear. You can also create new feature request in mongoose github page, if you really want this to be included in their builds.